# How to test different iOSes in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, xcode4, ios-simulator

I am finally done with my app. Testing begins! It works great in the most recent 4.3.2 but when I change the device version in simulator to something lesser and launch my app it automatically reverts to the newest 4.3.2 version. How do I overcome this and ensure my app runs on all iphones?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Figured it out! Set the deployment target in Project and Target to the lowest iOS. Next to the Run and Stop buttons, there is a drop down list "Scheme" select the deployment target. It should launch the simulator with the iOS version you select!

Answer (score 1):

To allow simulation in 3.1.3, you must install an old version of Xcode. If you are a registered iPhone developer, you can download Xcode 3.1.4 for Leopard with iPhone SDK 3.1.3 or Xcode 3.1.4 for Snow Leopard with iPhone SDK 3.1.3. Be careful to install these in a different location to your Xcode 3.2.3 with iOS3.2/iOS4 (either select a different hard disk or rename your existing /Developer directory before you install).

Regards

Karan Shah

Comment: So I am a bit confused. The iOS refers to the software on an iphone. So any iphone (whether released in 2008 or 2010) could have the latest iOS. Now, my question is, if it works on the latest iOS 4.3.2 does it mean it should theoretically work fine under earlier iOS releases?

Comment: @Alede: No, since you might be using classes, methods and symbols that are not available in older iOS versions. Testing for the availability the classes/methods/symbols and most importantly actually testing on these older versions is needed.